# Last unique entries above current row in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window-functions

I have a Spark dataframe with the following data:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "A", "2022-01-01", 30, 0), 
  (1, "A", "2022-01-02", 20, 30),
  (1, "B", "2022-01-03", 50, 20),
  (1, "A", "2022-01-04", 10, 70),
  (1, "B", "2022-01-05", 30, 60), 
  (1, "A", "2022-01-06", 0,  40), 
  (1, "C", "2022-01-07", 100,30), 
  (2, "D", "2022-01-08", 5, 0)
)).toDF("id", "event", "eventTimestamp", "amount", "expected")

display(df)
```

| id | event | eventTimestamp | amount | expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "A" | "2022-01-01" | 30 | 0 |
| 1 | "A" | "2022-01-02" | 20 | 30 |
| 1 | "B" | "2022-01-03" | 50 | 20 |
| 1 | "A" | "2022-01-04" | 10 | 70 |
| 1 | "B" | "2022-01-05" | 30 | 60 |
| 1 | "A" | "2022-01-06" | 0 | 40 |
| 1 | "C" | "2022-01-07" | 100 | 30 |
| 2 | "D" | "2022-01-08" | 5 | 0 |

I want to find the following for each row: The sum of all last entries (above the current row) for each id and each **unique** event. The desired outcome is in the column "expected".

E.g. for the order "C" I'd like to get the latest amounts for "A" and "B": 30 + 0 = 30

I tried the following query, however it would sum up the amounts of all previous orders, including duplications, (I'm not sure, if it's possible to apply a filter on the sum to take only distinct values):

```
val days = (x:Int) => x * 86400
val idWindow = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("eventTimestamp")
   .cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
   .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -days(1))

val res = df.withColumn("totalAmount", sum($"amount").over(idWindow))
```

Please note that the rangeBetween functionality is important for my use-case and should be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to convert amounts to diffs within (id, event) pairs, which allows you to calculate moving sum in the next step. That moving sum maintains latest amounts of each unique event.

```
df
  .withColumn("diff", coalesce($"amount" - lag($"amount", 1).over(wIdEvent), $"amount")).
  .withColumn("sum", sum($"diff").over(wId)).
  .withColumn("final", coalesce(lag($"sum", 1).over(wId), lit(0))).
  .orderBy($"eventTimestamp").show

+---+-----+--------------+------+--------+----+---+-----+
| id|event|eventTimestamp|amount|expected|diff|sum|final|
+---+-----+--------------+------+--------+----+---+-----+
|  1|    A|    2022-01-01|    30|       0|  30| 30|    0|
|  1|    A|    2022-01-02|    20|      30| -10| 20|   30|
|  1|    B|    2022-01-03|    50|      20|  50| 70|   20|
|  1|    A|    2022-01-04|    10|      70| -10| 60|   70|
|  1|    B|    2022-01-05|    30|      60| -20| 40|   60|
|  1|    A|    2022-01-06|     0|      40| -10| 30|   40|
|  1|    C|    2022-01-07|   100|      30| 100|130|   30|
|  2|    D|    2022-01-08|     5|       0|   5|  5|    0|
+---+-----+--------------+------+--------+----+---+-----+
```

Comment: Honestly I wasn't sure about your requirement on `rangeBetween`. But the results are matching. If you have a specific case where makes a difference please highlight it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About *rangeBetween* - an example usecase would be to aggregate only the events that happened until N days ago (ignore the last N days)